# Open all NC files in a directory and save them as Excel Sheet

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have 720 .NC files in one folder. I am trying to open the file and write all the data into an excel sheet. the scripts works perfectly for single file. Here is my code for single file:

```
import xarray as xr

file_name =  'dcbl.slice.11748.nc'
# Loading NetCDF dataset using xarray
data = xr.open_dataset('/Users/ismot/Downloads/LES_Data/u1.shf400.lhf040.512/' + file_name)

# convert the columns to dataframe using xarray
df = data[['x', 'y', 'time', 'C_sum_column_AVIRIS', 'C_sum_column_HyTES']].to_dataframe()

# write the dataframe to an excel file
df.to_excel(file_name + '.xlsx')
```

Now, I am trying to run the script for the all files in the directory. I have modified the scripts like this:

```
# import required module
import os
import xarray as xr
# assign directory
directory = '/Users/ismot/Downloads/LES_Data/u1.shf400.lhf040.512'
 
# list all files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    # checking if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
        
# write a function to open .NC files using xarray and convert them in excel sheet      
    def file_changer(filename):
        data = xr.open_dataset(str(filename))
        df = data[['x', 'y', 'time', 'C_sum_column_AVIRIS', 'C_sum_column_HyTES']].to_dataframe()
        df.to_excel(filename + '.xlsx')
    
# Run for multiple files
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.nc'):
    file_changer(file)
```

The scripts runs and gives no error. But it only prints the name of the files in the directory. It doesn't go over the 720 files and save them in the excel sheet. How can I fix it?

Comment: The code is slightly confusing. Why are you creating a function within a for loop? Currently you are printing files in one directory, but then trying to loop through nc files in the working directory. My guess is the glob.glob is returning nothing so the final loop does nothing

Comment: I'd also note that since the xarray portion of this question works fine, and you're just having trouble looping over files, this is a general python question, not an xarray question. but yes, I expect Robert's observation is the issue - you're not looping over files in the directory `directory`, but in the current directory.